# Instance of 'Future<String?>' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Why is returning Instance of 'Future<String?>' instead String value?

```
Future<String?> getUser() async {
    User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = await FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    String uid = user.uid;
    String? userName;

    // to get username from firebase
    return firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.exists) {
        var data = value.data();
        userName = data?["name"];
        print("There is data :$userName");
      } else {
        print("There no Data!");
      }
      return Future.value(userName);
    });
  }
```

I am trying to get String value?

Comment: Your function is asynchronous.  If it returns a value, that value *must* be a `Future`.  It is the caller's responsibility to `await` the returned `Future` to obtain the `String?` from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place you like to get data from this method use `await` & the method is needed to be async. like

```dart
 _myFunction() async{  
    final value  =  await getUser();
```

Also I will suggest to not mixing await and `.then`.

```dart
Future<String?> getUser() async {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String uid = user.uid;
  String? userName;

  // to get username from firebase
  final value = await firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
  if (value.exists) {
    var data = value.data();
    userName = data?["name"];
    print("There is data :$userName");
  } else {
    print("There no Data!");
  }
  return userName;
}
```

Comment: "to get data instead of future"... no, that still returns a Future, since to use await you must be in an async function which automatically returns a Future.  It's the *caller* that must deal with the future using await.  Not the invoked function.

Comment: Thanks, @RandalSchwartz, I misunderstood the issue.